# Unable to seed data in Lumen 8 project

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run a seeder in a lumen 8 project but have been unsuccessful for a while now. Here's the folder structure view

[image]

When I run `php artisan db:seed --class="Database\Seeds\SampleTableSeeder"` or `php artisan db:seed --class="Database\Seeders\Seeds\SampleTableSeeder"` or `php artisan db:seed --class=SampleTableSeeder` it fails and returns a target class not found like

> Target class [Database/Seeds/SampleTableSeeder] does not exist.

I have added the namespace to `SampleTableSeeder` to look like

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeds;

use App\Models\Sample;
class SampleTableSeeder
{
    // ....
}
```

And in `DatabaseSeeder` run function, I am calling it like this

```
$this->call('Database/Seeds/SampleTableSeeder');
```

What is the right way to run this particular seeder?

Comment: Any reason why you didn't place it inside the `seeders/` folder? That _should_ work out of the box. Does `composer du` help?

Comment: @brombeer I personally would put it in the `seeders/` but its an old project I am handling and this is how I met it. `composer du` did not help either

Answer (score 0):

`Database/Seeds` will never work, because you have not declare it on the `composer.json` section...

See [the original file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c0b60c0ac74e599122a6a417171798f609f16814/composer.json#L23-L29), it has this section:

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
}
```

You have to declare that new section:

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            "Database\\Seeds\\": "database/seeds/"
        }
    },
}
```

Then it will work, but I personally do NOT recommend to do that... you already have `Database/Seeders`...

---

Quick update, if running `php artisan db:seed --class="Database\Seeds\SampleTableSeeder"` does not work, try adding `\` at the beginning, like this `php artisan db:seed --class="\Database\Seeds\SampleTableSeeder"`

Comment: Yeah, I also do not recommend changing the composer autoload default. I will rather move the seeders into `seeders/`

Comment: Tried doing that even before I posted the question. It did not work. I have moved the seeders into the default `seeders/`